# Почему в AndroidStudio | Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle нет GradleProjects

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle

Ошибка:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/natalya/Documents/projects/flut_app/android/app/build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
     Your current JDK is located in  /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
     You can try some of the following options:
       - changing the IDE settings.
       - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
       - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

 Flutter Fix 
 [!] You need Java 11 or higher to build your app with this version of Gradle. 
                                                                               
 To get Java 11, update to the latest version of Android Studio on             
 https://developer.android.com/studio/install.                                 
                                                                               
 To check the Java version used by Flutter, run `flutter doctor -v`.           

Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Хочу поставить jdk 15, так как появляется ошибка, при компиляции проекта рис. 1. Пытался что-то найти в гугле, нашел на англ форуме как решают проблему jdk и gradle, но в моем AndroidStudio нет дополнительного функций в табе gradle   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все до основания просто. Нужно просто скачать JDK (dmg в случае с маком) и поставить его в PATH. В gradle.properties нужно указать путь до JDK через org.gradle.java.home. Затем flutter clean => flutter get packages